# Reverse Proxy on Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, geoserver

I am naive to apache and network management. I have GeoServer hosted on one of my virtual machine which works correctly by the URL as localhost/geoserver . Also, I have successfully mapped one link say abc.ac.in/pqr/ (Link changed) to the localhost of virtual machine displaying the index.html of apache. But when I try to access abc.ac.in/pqr/geoserver then I get an error as /geoserver was not found on this server. Also, the link gets changed to abc.ac.in/geoserver.

I have used the reverse proxy as below in the httpd conf of apache as below:-

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyPass "/geoserver" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
    ProxyPassReverse "/geoserver" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
</IfModule>
```

and uncommented below lines:-

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Please let me know whether is this the issue from configuration side or related to mapping from network side and the possible workaround if any.

Comment: Your question says *"... access abc.ac.in/pqr/geoserver"* and your ProxyPass says "/geoserver".  These have to match.  So either use `ProxyPass "/pqr/geoserver"` or try abc.ac.in/geoserver.

Comment: abc.ac.in/pqr/ is mapped till localhost so /geoserver should work fine.Tried your suggestion but got error as below:-                                                        
       Problem accessing /geoserver%22. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: `%22` is a `:` encoded.  Make sure your configuration does not have a `:` somewhere.